# print python output to file not working

Tags: python

i have the following function

```
outFile = open("svm_light/{0}/predictions-average.txt".format(hashtag), "a")
with open('svm_light/{0}/predictions-{1}'.format(hashtag,segMent)) as f:
    tot_sum = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(f, 1):
        val = float(x)
        tot_sum += val            
        average = tot_sum/i
        outFile.write(average)
```

I'm simply trying to print the output for each average to 1 average per line.
however im getting the following error...

```
  outFile.write(average)            
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

if I simply change my program to this:

```
with open('svm_light/{0}/predictions-{1}'.format(hashtag,segMent)) as f:
    tot_sum = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(f, 1):
         val = float(x)
         tot_sum += val            
         average = tot_sum/i
         print average
```

prints the following:

```
  @ubuntu:~/Documents/tweets/svm_light$ python2.7 tweetAverage2.py

  0.428908289104
  0.326446277105
  0.63672940322
  0.600035561829
  0.666699795857
```

it prints the  output neatly to the screen, but i would like to save it 1 average per line, much like is showing in the actual output.
Im new to python, and am using 2.7 under ubuntu.

**UPDATE**

thanx to a quick response, introduced the str function. However, it prints an empty file, i can see the file has contents for a bit, and then its gone. most likely its being overwritten the whole time. So im placing this print function somehwere it shouldnt be, but where?

Comment: `outFile.write(str(average) + "\n")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert `average` to a string before writing it to a file, you can use `str()` or string formatting for that.

```
outFile.write(str(average))
```

Help on `file.write`:

```
>>> print file.write.__doc__
write(str) -> None.  Write string str to file.  #expects a string

Note that due to buffering, flush() or close() may be needed before
the file on disk reflects the data written.
```

**Update:**

```
outFile_name = "svm_light/{0}/predictions-average.txt".format(hashtag)
in_file_name = 'svm_light/{0}/predictions-{1}'.format(hashtag,segMent)
with open(in_file_name) as f, open(outFile_name, 'w') as outFile:
    tot_sum = 0
    for i,x in enumerate(f, 1):
        val = float(x)
        tot_sum += val            
        average = tot_sum/i
        outFile.write(average + '\n') # '\n' adds a new-line
```

Comment: @RHK-S8 open the `outFile` in append mode(`'a'`), if you're writing to the same file in a loop.

Comment: @RHK-S8 open the `outFile` using `with` statement, your code didn't work because you didn't close or flushed the `outFile`. Try my updated code.

Comment: i copied your code, it produces 1 line with 1 average. instead ofmultiple averages, per line

Comment: @RHK-S8 I guess I didn't indent the write part properly. But there are no multiple averages here, you just calculated one average at the end of the loop.

Comment: no probs :) see the update, it prints 5 averages (input was 5 files) to the screen, its that output i want in a file.

Comment: @RHK-S8 I think you needed a `'\n'`, `outFile.write(average + '\n')` should do it.

Comment: `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'float' and 'str'` it gives me that error.

Comment: @RHK-S8 `outFile.write(str(average) + '\n')`. :)

Comment: ok it sort of works, it prints different averages than the list i gave above (i.e. different than the output-to-screen), so im printing wrong somewhere in the loop...soo weird how it works for the normal output, but not to file

Comment: fixed it! it didnt have outputfile to append mode